# Android my app prevents camera from recording

Tags: android, android-camera

I made an app which uses cordova plugin to run a SIPML5 web app.
When my app runs in background, if i open camera, the record button is disabled.
If I kill the app, sometimes the record button is enabled again.
I don't know how to fix this. My app does not uses.

**Here is my manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alonia"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="2224"
    android:versionName="2.0.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AloniaRunOnStartup"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".AloniaService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks,
Andi

Comment: Maybe your app opens camera and does not release it **onPause**, or does not release MediaRecorder

Answer (score 0):

It's because, unfortunately, two android apps cannot have access to the same mic at the same time.  This is a broadcast issue and so because of your "record audio" permission, your camera won't be able to record.

Here's another link of people trying to do the same: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36982217